# Add Id from latest insert to another table retroactively

Tags: sql

So, I'm updating an SQL Database. I have a table SiteTank which as a compound PK SiteId and Number. I have another table, Measure, that have measures for all tanks for all sites, and the date at which the measure measure was taken.
I want to update SiteTank to hold the Id of the last measure for each, well... SiteTank. For the future, I'll probably put a trigger in place so that when a new measure is entered, it'll update the last entered measure in SiteTank, but for now, I need to find retroactively the last measure for each SiteTank and add it's Id.

I added the new field to SiteTank, but I'm not really sure how to make this update. I can get the Id of the last measure for each SiteTank with a kinda complex SELECT, but I'm not sure how to proceed with inserting that Id.I was thinking maybe a Stored proc that takes a SiteId and TankNumber, then find and add the last measure Id ; then call the stored proc for each row in SiteTank ?

Thanks for any help !

The Select that lets me get the Id I need :

```
SELECT
    P.[Id]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        P.[SiteId],
        P.[SiteTankNumber],
        MAX(P.[AsOfDate]) AS [MeasureDate]
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            M.[SiteId],
            M.[SiteTankNumber],
            M.[AsOfDate],
            M.[CreatedDate],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.[SiteId], M.[SiteTankNumber], M.[AsOfDate] ORDER BY M.[CreatedDate] DESC) AS [RN]
        FROM
            [dbo].[Measure] M
    ) P
    GROUP BY
        P.[SiteId],
        P.[SiteTankNumber]
) AS LM
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        M.[Id],
        M.[SiteId],
        M.[SiteTankNumber],
        M.[AsOfDate],
        M.[CreatedDate],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.[SiteId], M.[SiteTankNumber], M.[AsOfDate] ORDER BY M.[CreatedDate] DESC) AS [RN]
    FROM
        [dbo].[Measure] M
) P 
    ON 
        P.[SiteId] = LM.[SiteId] 
        AND P.[SiteTankNumber] = LM.[SiteTankNumber] 
        AND P.[AsOfDate] = LM.[MeasureDate]
        AND P.[RN] = 1
WHERE
    P.[SiteId] = [SiteTank].[SiteId] 
    AND P.[SiteTankNumber] = [SiteTank].[Number]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using a CTE to fetch the required fields, and then use it to perform a JOIN UPDATE:

```
WITH LastMeasure AS (
                     SELECT SiteId, SiteTankNumber, CreatedDate, MAX(AsOfDate) AS MeasureDate
                     FROM Measure
                     GROUP BY SiteId, SiteTankNumber, CreatedDate
                     ),
 LastMeasuring AS (
                   SELECT SiteId, SiteTankNumber, MAX(CreatedDate) AS LastMeasureDate
                   FROM Measure
                   GROUP BY SiteId, SiteTankNumber
                  )

UPDATE SiteTank
SET LastMeasureDate = LastMeasure.MeasureDate
FROM SiteTank
INNER JOIN LastMeasure ON SiteTank.SiteId = LastMeasure.SiteId 
                       AND SiteTank.SiteTankNumber = LastMeasure.SiteTankNumber
INNER JOIN LastMeasuring ON LastMeasure.SiteId = LastMeasuring.SiteId
                         AND LastMeasure.SiteTankNumber = LastMeasuring.SiteTankNumber
                         AND LastMeasure.CreatedDate = LastMeasuring.LastMeasureDate;
```

This should solve your question unless i missed something.